# Bindings don't show up on my bound control

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, dependency-properties

I have a derived class (i hope i have created correctly)

```
    <ToggleButton x:Class="Project.QuestionControls.spriteToggleButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    xmlns:local="clr-Project.QuestionControls"
    x:Name="spriteButton"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="57" Width="294" VerticalAlignment="Center"  d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" IsEnabled="True">
    <ToggleButton.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RectToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlighted" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Idle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Selected" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Idle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlighted" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Selected" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Selected" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Idle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlighted" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <!-- any bindings here don't work -->
                            <local:spriteView x:Name="Idle" Width="294" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Sprite="{Binding idleSprite}"  />
                            <local:spriteView x:Name="Selected" Width="294" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Sprite="{Binding selectedSprite}" />
                            <local:spriteView x:Name="Highlighted" Width="294" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Sprite="{Binding highlightedSprite}" />

                            <ContentControl x:Name="Content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="70,8,71,15" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" />

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Resources>

    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="RectToggleButton"/>
    </ToggleButton.Style>

</ToggleButton>
```

When I do `{Binding idleSprite}` the binding doesn't do anything, I even tried with a string property to show up in a TextBlock but to no avail.

This is what my code looks behind for this control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Project.QuestionControls
{
    public partial class spriteToggleButton : ToggleButton
    {

        public Quiz.Sprite idleSprite { get; set; }
        public static DependencyProperty idleSpriteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "idleSprite", typeof(Quiz.Sprite), typeof(spriteToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(new Quiz.Sprite(){ rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0), spriteSheet = "default.png" }
        ));

        public Quiz.Sprite selectedSprite { get; set; }
        public static DependencyProperty selectedSpriteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "selectedSprite", typeof(Quiz.Sprite), typeof(spriteToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(new Quiz.Sprite() { rect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0), spriteSheet = "default.png" }
        ));

        public Quiz.Sprite highlightedSprite { get; set; }
        public static DependencyProperty highlightedSpriteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "highlightedSprite", typeof(Quiz.Sprite), typeof(spriteToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(new Quiz.Sprite() { rect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0), spriteSheet = "default.png" }
        ));

        public spriteToggleButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Dictionary<string, Quiz.Sprite> Sprites
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<string,Quiz.Sprite>)GetValue(SpritesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SpritesProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty SpritesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "Sprites", typeof(Dictionary<string, Quiz.Sprite>), typeof(spriteToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(new Dictionary<string, Quiz.Sprite>(), OnSpritesPropertyValueChanged));

        private static void OnSpritesPropertyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as spriteToggleButton;
            var sprites = e.NewValue as Dictionary<string, Quiz.Sprite>;

            control.idleSprite = sprites["idle"];
            control.selectedSprite = sprites["selected"];
            control.highlightedSprite = sprites["highlighted"];
        }

        public string Text { get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); } set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); } }

        public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(spriteToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata("", OnTextPropertyValueChanged));

        private static void OnTextPropertyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as spriteToggleButton;
            var contentText = e.NewValue as string;

            control.spriteButton.Content = contentText;
        }

        public Boolean Selected { get { return (Boolean)GetValue(SelectedProperty); } set { SetValue(SelectedProperty, value); } }

        public static DependencyProperty SelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Selected", typeof(Boolean), typeof(spriteToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectedPropertyValueChanged));

        private static void OnSelectedPropertyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as spriteToggleButton;
            var selectedValue = (Boolean)e.NewValue;

            control.spriteButton.IsChecked = selectedValue;
        }

    }
}
```

`OnSpritesPropertyValueChanged` runs but the bindings still don't work, I even add a `Loaded` event to check and the Sprites property was the defaults instead of what I had set it to (but maybe `Loaded` runs before dependencyproperties are set)

It stopped working around the time I updated the UserControl into a derived ToggleButton, which I may have done wrong.

I hope this is enough detail to fix this issue.

In the ListBox that used the spriteToggleButton I send properties and they get sent down perfectly like this.

```
<local:spriteToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding text}" Sprites="{Binding Path=DataContext.UISprites, ElementName=questionField}" Selected="{Binding Selected}" Checked="optionChecked" />
```

Except when I repeat the process inside of spriteToggleButton but i have dependency properties registered there, so maybe there's a missing step with datacontext.

Comment: Debug output window uses to yell when there is a binding problem. Did you check it?

Comment: Strange that you use TemplateBinding for Content, but simple Binding for the sprites. Is the DataContext set up correctly?

Comment: 'Selected' property not found on 'Project.Quiz+Answer' 'Project.Quiz+Answer' ... 'highlightedSprite' property not found .. etc

Comment: @Jan how would i set up the data context? like this  DataContext="{Binding .}

Comment: I've added more info, I had issues trying to use the spriteToggleButton without datacontext, just by passing properties so maybe i'm missing some wiring code.

Comment: Why don't you use TemplateBinding instead of Binding?

Comment: @Jan that crashes. should it use the properties in the code behind if i use TemplateBinding? unfortunately it crashes for me.

Comment: @JanSlodicka let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2097/discussion-between-joseph-le-brech-and-jan-slodicka)

Comment: What does it mean "crashes"? Hard to answer if you don't come with complete info right away. Maybe because the binding started to work finally. Check also the TargetType, maybe that's the problem. This is my last reply, that's way a general comment: Read debug output. Read exception details. Check properties of your button at the moment of the crash. Analyze all that information and you should get the answer.

Comment: I've looked up RelativeSource this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635(VS.95).aspx and it seems to be passing the property down.

Comment: it's my fault the getters and setters for the properties needed to use the DependencyProperty using GetValue